# Past price data has predictive power, it's not 50/50

Tags: time-series, predictive-models

They say that it's impossible (for ordinary men, with simple statistics and math) to predict future stock price based on the past stock price.

But that's not exactly true. As you still can predict something, and with quite a high certainty.

You can predict future volatility based on past volatility. You don't need complex math to conclude that there's a good chance (maybe not >90% but probably >60%) that next month for highly volatile in past stockslike AMD, or Tesla going to be more volatile than for less historically volatile stocks like McDonald's or Procter & Gamble.

- So, **volatility** is one thing you can predict from the past.
- The **head part of the probability distribution** could be predicted. The shape of the tail of the distribution may be not very precise, but the shape of the head should be more or less close to reality. I.e. we know the probability of price changes for say 90% of stock history, and don't know for say 10% when rare unexpected jumps happens.

**What else statistical or other properties of the future prices could be predicted based on past prices and other data like volume, spreads etc**? What **easily observable** (like with volatility - you can easily observe there's connection between past and future) conclusions could be made? Maybe some dumb or obvious properties, we never though about, I'm interested in building a list of it.

Comment: Sure, you can predict that Tesla will be more volatile than your average utility stock, but isn't the trick to predict future volatility of Tesla, relative to past volatility of Tesla? In other words, is Tesla going to be more or less volatile next week than last week?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting deep question. The deeper answer lies in the underlying causality - the process being studied. Let me make a clear distinction.

In classic physics we know that $F = m \cdot a \; $ and that $\; E = M \cdot C^2$. These equations hold always, at least we have all reason to believe this, outside maybe black holes.

In economy, this is different. Economy is about markets and equilibria - and market conditions change all the time. The **causality of economics** is different to that of classic physics. A new successful competitor joins a market, and the market conditions change. The global economy goes into a recession and the market conditions change.

So what can be predicted within economics?

- Expected values can be estimated
- Price elasticity is a more stable factor
- Risk of defaulting a loan
- Risk of bankruptcy
- Long-term correlations between individual share prices and a share market index

These are a few examples I could think of.